# Is there a reliable estimate of what proportion of adults in a country are in debt at a given time?

Tags: debt

Is there a reliable estimate of what proportion of adults in a given country are in debt at a given time? With "debt" covering student debt, debt secured by mortgages on property, credit card debt, etc.?